# React Native Oval Scroll

Tags: react-native, scroll, scrollview, flatlist

How can I do a similar **oval scroll**?

What can I use for this?

[image]

Comment: I have never heard of Oval Scroll, I even tried to google "oval scroll" but I couldn't find anything either. It's not clear what you are trying to achieve

Comment: This is a list, for example, consisting of 20 items, the scroll should work ovally, like the picture

Comment: I think he needs [something like that](https://reactnative.dev/docs/assets/DatePickerIOS/maximumDate.gif)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the assumption that you want something like [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/assets/DatePickerIOS/maximumDate.gif), I wrote a [simple example](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-forest-k13o7?file=/src/App.js)

If someday the link turns out to be broken, below I attach the code additionally

```jsx
import React, { useCallback, useState, useRef } from "react";
import {
  FlatList,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  Dimensions,
  Animated
} from "react-native";

const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");
const screenMiddle = height / 2;
const itemScaleOffset = height / 3;

const DATA = new Array(20).fill(0).map((...args) => ({
  id: args[1],
  title: args[1]
}));
// args[1] is an index, just I hate warnings

const Item = ({ title, offsetY }) => {
  const [scrollEdges, setScrollEdges] = useState({
    top: 0,
    middle: 0,
    bottom: 0
  });

  const onLayout = useCallback(
    ({
      nativeEvent: {
        layout: { top, height }
      }
    }) =>
      setScrollEdges((edges) => ({
        ...edges,
        top: top - itemScaleOffset - screenMiddle,
        middle: top + height / 2 - screenMiddle,
        bottom: top + height + itemScaleOffset - screenMiddle
      })),
    []
  );

  const scale = offsetY.interpolate({
    inputRange: [scrollEdges.top, scrollEdges.middle, scrollEdges.bottom],
    outputRange: [0.66, 1, 0.66],
    extrapolate: "clamp"
  });

  return (
    <Animated.View
      onLayout={onLayout}
      style={[
        {
          transform: [
            {
              scale
            }
          ]
        },
        styles.item
      ]}
    >
      <Text style={styles.title}>{title}</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
};

const keyExtractor = ({ id }) => id.toString();

const App = () => {
  const offsetY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

  const renderItem = useCallback(
    ({ item: { title } }) => <Item title={title} offsetY={offsetY} />,
    [offsetY]
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <FlatList
        data={DATA}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={keyExtractor}
        onScroll={Animated.event(
          [
            {
              nativeEvent: {
                contentOffset: {
                  y: offsetY
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          {
            useNativeDriver: false
          }
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    flex: 1
  },
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#f9c2ff",
    padding: 20,
    marginVertical: 8,
    marginHorizontal: 16
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 32
  }
});

export default App;
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you should use Reanimated 2 who has a very easy sintaxis and also very powerful. Maybe in combination with RNGestureHandler.